# ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'invalid sender'} error, with compatible chainId

Tags: python, bsc

[image: error message]

Hey! I am making a bridge from bsc -> arbitrum, and I have a problem while signing message.

The code for making trx is:

```
case 'bsc':
        match user_info['currency']:
            case 'eth':
                tx = unicorn.functions.transfer( eth_orbiter , 
                    value,
                    ).build_transaction({
                     'chainId': chain_id,
                     'gas': gas_limit,
                     'maxFeePerGas': gas,
                     'maxPriorityFeePerGas': web3.to_wei('1', 'gwei'),
                     'nonce': nonce,
                     })
```

When I debug the code I can see that chainId is correct. What could be wrong?
[image: debug info]

Answer (score 0):

fixed by changing the code to:

```
tx = unicorn.functions.transfer( weth_orbiter , 
                    value,
                    ).build_transaction({
                     'chainId': chain_id,
                     'gas': gas_limit,
                     'gasPrice': gas,
                     'nonce': nonce,
                     })
```

Comment: for some reason contract transfer acts different with bsc and other networks for me xd